# Is there any possibility for two sensors accessing on the Raspberry PI2 pins (like SDA and SDL) ?

Tags: raspberry-pi2, iot, windows-iot-core-10

I am working on IoT Technology, in my current project I want to connect two sensors like BMP280 and TSL 2561 by using Raspberry PI 2.

But these two sensors are using the Same I2C Bus Pins (I2C1 SDA and I2C1 SDL on the Raspberry PI2.

Please tell me how can I use the above two pins for two sensors.

-Kishore

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more suitable for [raspberrypi.se] instead. This site is for programming related questions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the I2C [protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C)? I2C is kinda of a serial communication bus, and you can attack multiple slave devices to an I2C bus master.

In your case, just share the SDA and SDL pins on the raspberry pi, those two sensor are distinguished by the unique device IDs when you discuss with them.

Not to mention that you have different sensors(BMP280 and TSI 2561), the manufacture ID could be just enough for differentiation.

We could even attach multiple I2c slave devices to the same I2c bus, the way we differentiate them is to use different address(normally 3 address pins). However, the total number of slaves would be limited, up to 8 though.